# How to string join one column with another columns - pandas

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe

I just came across this question, how do I do `str.join` by one column to join the other, here is my `DataFrame`:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 'b': ['hello', 'good', 'great', 'nice']})
   a      b
0  a  hello
1  b   good
2  c  great
3  d   nice
```

I would like the `a` column to join the values in the `b` column, so my desired output is:

```
   a          b
0  a  haealalao
1  b    gbobobd
2  c  gcrcecact
3  d    ndidcde
```

How would I go about that?

Hope you can see the correlation with this, here is one example with the first row that you can do in python:

```
>>> 'a'.join('hello')
'haealalao'
>>>
```

Just like in the desired output.

I think it might be useful to know how two columns can interact. `join` might not be the best example but there are other functions that you could do. It could maybe be useful if you use `split` to `split` on the other columns, or replace the characters in the other columns with something else.

**P.S. I have a self-answer below.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## TL;DR

The below code is the fastest answer I could figure out from this question:

```
it = iter(df['a'])
df['b'] = [next(it).join(i) for i in df['b']]
```

The above code first does a generator of the `a` column, then you can use `next` for getting the next value every time, then in the list comprehension it joins the two strings.

### Long answer:

Going to show my solutions:

**Solution 1:**

To use a `list` comprehension and a generator:

```
it = iter(df['a'])
df['b'] = [next(it).join(i) for i in df['b']]
print(df)
```

**Solution 2:**

Group by the index, and `apply` and `str.join` the two columns' value:

```
df['b'] = df.groupby(df.index).apply(lambda x: x['a'].item().join(x['b'].item()))
print(df)
```

**Solution 3:**

Use a `list` comprehension that iterates through both columns and `str.join`s:

```
df['b'] = [x.join(y) for x, y in df.values.tolist()]
print(df)
```

These codes all output:

```
   a          b
0  a  haealalao
1  b    gbobobd
2  c  gcrcecact
3  d    ndidcde
```

#### Timing:

Now it's time to move on to timing with the `timeit` module, here is the code we use to time:

```
from timeit import timeit
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 'b': ['hello', 'good', 'great', 'nice']})
def u11_1():
    it = iter(df['a'])
    df['b'] = [next(it).join(i) for i in df['b']]
    
def u11_2():
    df['b'] = df.groupby(df.index).apply(lambda x: x['a'].item().join(x['b'].item()))
    
def u11_3():
    df['b'] = [x.join(y) for x, y in df.values.tolist()]

print('Solution 1:', timeit(u11_1, number=5))
print('Solution 2:', timeit(u11_2, number=5))
print('Solution 3:', timeit(u11_3, number=5))
```

Output:

```
Solution 1: 0.007374127670871819
Solution 2: 0.05485127553865618
Solution 3: 0.05787154087587698
```

So the first solution is the quickest, using a generator.

Comment: as an aside, series have an [_iter_](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.__iter__.html)

Comment: @sammywemmy Oh yeah thats true, you can post that as an answer if you want

Comment: Not really. Learning from your code. You could also try it with a larger data and see if the speeds change.

Comment: @sammywemmy Yeah.

Comment: i think your function arent getting the same df to process

Comment: @AkashRanjan They are

Answer (score 2):

I tried achieving the output using `df.apply`

```
>>> df.apply(lambda x: x['a'].join(x['b']), axis=1)
0    haealalao
1      gbobobd
2    gcrcecact
3      ndidcde
dtype: object
```

Timing it for performance comparison,

```
from timeit import timeit
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 'b': ['hello', 'good', 'great', 'nice']})

def u11_1():
    it = iter(df['a'])
    df['b'] = [next(it).join(i) for i in df['b']]

def u11_2():
    df['b'] = df.groupby(df.index).apply(lambda x: x['a'].item().join(x['b'].item()))

def u11_3():
    df['b'] = [x.join(y) for x, y in df.values.tolist()]

def u11_4():
    df['c'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['a'].join(x['b']), axis=1)

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 'b': ['hello', 'good', 'great', 'nice']})
print('Solution 1:', timeit(u11_1, number=5))
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 'b': ['hello', 'good', 'great', 'nice']})
print('Solution 2:', timeit(u11_2, number=5))
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 'b': ['hello', 'good', 'great', 'nice']})
print('Solution 3:', timeit(u11_3, number=5))
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 'b': ['hello', 'good', 'great', 'nice']})
print('Solution 4:', timeit(u11_4, number=5))
```

Note that I am reinitializing df before every line so that all the functions process the same dataframe. It can also be done by passing the df as a parameter to the function.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another solution using `zip` and `list comprehension`. Should be better than `df.apply`:

```
In [1576]: df.b = [i.join(j) for i,j in zip(df.a, df.b)]

In [1578]: df
Out[1578]: 
   a          b
0  a  haealalao
1  b    gbobobd
2  c  gcrcecact
3  d    ndidcde
```